# how to keep modal display when there are an error

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog

hello everyone, i have an issue  to keep  the modal display , the error display but i have to click an the button add to see the detail of error because the modal disappear when i click to submit button , any idea to keep modal display when there are an  error  without click back to button add ,   please help me

> this is my modal  blade.php

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
      <!--  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>-->
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Ajouter Fournisseur </b></h4>
      </div>
      <form action="{{ route('addFournisseur') }}" method="post" id="Register">
            {{csrf_field()}}
          <div class="modal-body bgColorWhite">

                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            <label for="nom">Nom :</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" id="nom" required placeholder="Entrer nom" value="{{old('nom')}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                      <p style="color:red;"><span style="color:red;" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('nom', ':message') }}</span></p>
                        </div>

                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="email">Email :</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Entrer email" value="{{old('email')}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <p style="color:red;"><span style="color:red;" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('email', ':message') }}</span></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="telephone">Téléphone :</label>
                        <input type="phoneNumber" class="form-control" name="telephone" id="telephone" required placeholder="Entrer numéro téléphone" value="{{old('telephone')}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <p style="color:red;"><span style="color:red;" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('telephone', ':message') }}</span></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="fax">Fax :</label>
                        <input type="phoneNumber" class="form-control" name="fax" id="fax" placeholder="Entrer Fax : optionnel" value="{{old('fax')}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <p style="color:red;"><span style="color:red;" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('fax', ':message') }}</span></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="ville">Ville :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ville" id="ville" required placeholder="Entrer ville" value="{{old('ville')}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <p style="color:red;"><span style="color:red;" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('ville', ':message') }}</span></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="adresse1">Adresse :</label>
                        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" name="adresse1" id="adresse1" required placeholder="Entrer adresse" value="{{old('adresse1')}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <p style="color:red;"><span style="color:red;" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('adresse1', ':message') }}</span></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label for="adresse2">Adresse 2 :</label>
                        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" name="adresse2" id="adresse2" placeholder="Entrer 2éme adresse : optionnel " value="{{old('adresse2')}}" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker form-control-feedback"></span>
                        <p style="color:red;"><span style="color:red;" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('adresse2', ':message') }}</span></p>
                      </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer bg-info">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()" data-dismiss="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Fermer</button>

            <button type="submit" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()"  class="btn btn-primary" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Enregistrer</button>

          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> and this is my custum request  FournisseurRequest.php

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nom' => 'required|min:2|max:25',
            'email' => 'required|unique:fournisseurs|email',
            'telephone' => 'required|unique:fournisseurs|numeric',
            'fax' => 'unique:fournisseurs|max:25|numeric',
            'ville' => 'required|string|min:3|max:10',
            'adresse1' => 'required|string|min:2|max:100',
            'adresse2' => 'max:100'
        ];
    }
```

> this is my controller

```
     public function addFournisseur(FournisseurRequest $request)
      {
        Fournisseur::create($request->all());
        Session::flash('message','le Fournisseur '.$request->nom.' a été crée avec succès');
         return back();
}
```

> and this is my route

```
Route::POST('/addFournisseur','FournisseurController@addFournisseur')->name('addFournisseur');
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: bro i want to display errors of validation in the modal when there are an erros that's all , you have any ideas ?